# Java - For loop within ArrayList<String> method only returns one element

Tags: for-loop, arraylist, jtable

I am trying to use an ArrayList of string values from one table, modify the strings based on whether or not the string ends with ".tif" or ".tiff", then transfer the resulting strings to a new table.  However, when I invoke this method, the new table only receives the first modified string.  I'm not sure what is wrong with my logic, the first element of the original table would be checked to see if it satisfies a condition (either ending in ".tif" or ".tiff") then from there that string would be modified, added to the ArrayList fData, then iterate to the next table value.  I don't understand why the method doesn't return more than one element contained within fData?

```
    public ArrayList<String> getTableData() {   
       StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
       String fString = null;  
       ArrayList<String> fData = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(filePaths != null) {          
            int size = filePaths.size();                
            for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
                String pathName = filePaths.get(i);
                if (pathName.endsWith(".tif")) {
                    int pathLength = pathName.length();
                    str = new StringBuilder(filePaths.get(i));
                    str.insert(pathLength - 4, "_Data");
                    fString = str.toString();
                    fData.add(fString);

                    tableModel2.addRow(new String[] { fString });
                    return fData;
                }

                else if (pathName.endsWith(".tiff")) {
                        int pathLength = pathName.length();
                        str = new StringBuilder(filePaths.get(i));
                        str.insert(pathLength - 5, "_Data");
                        fString = str.toString();
                        fData.add(fString);

                        tableModel2.addRow(new String[] { fString });
                        return fData;
                }

            }
            tableModel2.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
        return null;        
    }

    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are returning from `getTableData()` as soon as you do a single replacement.  Instead, you should return only after having iterated over every file path.

Remove the `return` statements inside the loops and instead replace `return null` at the end with `return fData`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much! My understanding of return statements must be off then, I figured that the result of each iteration would have to be returned so that it could be "stored" before the next iteration, but that seems to be faulty logic.